# How to select only customer data and sum of that at bottom of table as row using sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have sql query.
this query is providing me a lots of record of customer and that voucher and order subtotal but i want sum of debit and credit row and credit and debit column sum at bottom position of table.

so guide me how can i achieve this table using by query.

this is my sql query.

```
declare @Credit decimal(18,2)
declare @Debit decimal(18,2) 

select @debit= SUM(sd.SubTotal) 
from SalesOrderDetails sd 
left join SalesOrder so 
    on sd.SalesOrderId = so.SalesOrderId 

select @credit = SUM(Amount) from Vouchers 

SELECT CustomerId,
    OrderDate, 
    VoucherType, 
    VoucherNo, 
    SUM(Debit) as Debit, 
    SUM(Credit) as Credit
FROM (SELECT so.CustomerId, 
            so.OrderDate ,
            'Sales' As VoucherType, 
            '' AS VoucherNo,
            a.Total As Debit
            , NULL As Credit
       from SalesOrder so 
       inner join (
                   SELECT SalesOrderId,
                          sum(SubTotal) AS Total
                   FROM SalesOrderDetails             
                   group by SalesOrderId
                  )as a 
            on so.SalesOrderId = a.SalesOrderId
        UNION ALL
        SELECT V.CustomerId
               ,v.VoucherDate As OrderDate
               , 'Receipt' AS VoucherType
               ,v.VoucherNumber AS VoucherNo
               ,NULL AS Debit
               ,v.Amount AS Credit
         from Vouchers v 
       ) ledger
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((CustomerId),(OrderDate, VoucherType, VoucherNo), ())
```

i have attached my output image.
[image]

in my image i got this result but that is very messy process so give me a proper solution for this.

Comment: If you have written this query by yourself then I think you are competent enough to achieve what you want

Comment: yes i have written this from internet help. but i  want other query which is short and i can achieve this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a HAVING Clause which happens after the grouping and aggregating?

```
....
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((CustomerId),(OrderDate, VoucherType, VoucherNo), ())
HAVING VoucherType Is Null
```

Comment: i know it is possible. if any other way to write short query and get fast data.

Comment: Yes it is possible. I will need a better explanation of what you are trying to achieve though? What are the rows without a voucher type ?

Comment: i need customer id and total of debit and credit customer wise and. table last row display all customers total of debit and credit.

Comment: Please can you show the Actual Execution plan with costs. It would be helpful if you identified the item with the highest cost. It's possibly missing indexes that is causing your delay.

Comment: if you have any idea so tell me how can i achieve that.